# Manipulate ListView from MySQL database

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) and trying to manipulate `ListView` from `MySQL` database but my app crashes and LogCat says:

```
11-28 11:06:42.093: E/AndroidRuntime(874): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wintel.vasonapps/com.wintel.vasonapps.AllRBT}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Though I have a ListView named `list`. Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a xml file for each item, named `list_item.xml`

```
    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anybody say why my app crashes? If further code is needed please tell me I'll edit this question with that code. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** This is `AllRBT.java`, after setting ID an error comes from here line 57

```
package com.wintel.vasonapps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllRBT extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/test/apps.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_rbt);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute(); //Line 57, this line throws error

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                  //      EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                //in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                //startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllRBT.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ring back tones. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                      //      NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    //startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllRBT.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596): Activity com.wintel.vasonapps.AllRBT has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cd2c88 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,144} that was originally added here
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.wintel.vasonapps.AllRBT has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cd2c88 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,144} that was originally added here
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at com.wintel.vasonapps.AllRBT$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllRBT.java:117)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
11-28 11:39:54.212: E/WindowManager(1596):  at com.wintel.vasonapps.AllRBT.onCreate(AllRBT.java:57)
```

Comment: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Answer (score 0):

Change your listview id in .xml file to and extend your activity to ListActivity

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```